# How to remove symbols only from an array or filter to have only array with numbers? [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Given such array & as I am working on Password Generator project by myself, I want to make an input be filled with numbers and letters only [Remove Symbols] and other time  remove Numbers only!

```
const characters = [
  "A",
  "B",
  "C",
  "D",
  "E",
  "F",
  "G",
  "H",
  "I",
  "J",
  "K",
  "L",
  "M",
  "N",
  "O",
  "P",
  "Q",
  "R",
  "S",
  "T",
  "U",
  "V",
  "W",
  "X",
  "Y",
  "Z",
  "a",
  "b",
  "c",
  "d",
  "e",
  "f",
  "g",
  "h",
  "i",
  "j",
  "k",
  "l",
  "m",
  "n",
  "w",
  "x",
  "y",
  "z",
  0,
  1,
  2,
  3,
  4,
  5,
  6,
  7,
  8,
  9,
  "#",
  "$",
  "%",
  "^",
  "&",
  "*",
  ",",
  "|",
  ":",
  ";",
  "<",
  ">",
  ".",
  "?",
  "/",
];
```

SO I want if user chooses to make a password without any numbers to filter that from the array!

Comment: Why not have three separate arrays then and combine them as needed?

Comment: Thanks Sebastian but the best way to write DRY code is ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
console.log('numbers', getCharacters().filter(char => typeof char === 'number'))

console.log('characters', getCharacters().filter(char => char.match?.(/[A-Za-z]/)))

console.log('symbols', getCharacters().filter(char => typeof char !== 'number' && !char.match?.(/[A-Za-z]/)))

function getCharacters() {
  return  [
  "A",
  "B",
  "C",
  "D",
  "E",
  "F",
  "G",
  "H",
  "I",
  "J",
  "K",
  "L",
  "M",
  "N",
  "O",
  "P",
  "Q",
  "R",
  "S",
  "T",
  "U",
  "V",
  "W",
  "X",
  "Y",
  "Z",
  "a",
  "b",
  "c",
  "d",
  "e",
  "f",
  "g",
  "h",
  "i",
  "j",
  "k",
  "l",
  "m",
  "n",
  "w",
  "x",
  "y",
  "z",
  0,
  1,
  2,
  3,
  4,
  5,
  6,
  7,
  8,
  9,
  "#",
  "$",
  "%",
  "^",
  "&",
  "*",
  ",",
  "|",
  ":",
  ";",
  "<",
  ">",
  ".",
  "?",
  "/",
];
}
```